# ASP.Net User Controls PubSub

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

Is there any way for one user control to raise an event that is handled by another user control without going through the page?  I am using Umbraco and do not have access to the page object.

--*Edit*--

Umbraco has the idea of Macro's (user controls) that it loads into pages.  I can't access the page directly as this is part of the framework.

There is a publish subscribe (pubsub) pattern that I know would fit my needs well (2 user controls that need to talk to each other) but am unsure how to hook it up in ASP.Net without the page object.

ANy help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'm not using that particular framework, so if you could provide more details, more people would be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend that you use Webforms MVP if you want to do that, it has a concept of cross-presenter messaging, allowing you to raise a message on one presenter which is consumed by another.

There's a [video of how to use it](http://wiki.webformsmvp.com/index.php?title=SC009) on their site.

Comment: Have you used this iin Umbraco?  What I need is pretty simple, I have a user control for controls that is shared on every page all I need to do is raise events that are handled by different user controls i.e. Save event